# OpenGL - Texture not rendering properly

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to render a cube with a wood texture (all faces of the cube with the same texture), but the texture is not being rendered as it should (looks like the texture is trasparent at some parts):

[image: outside the cube]

But if look inside the cube, it seems to be rendering properly:

:[image]

Here is the .obj file that I'm reading from (with the texture coords and vertices):

```
mtllib crate.mtl
o Cube_Cube.002
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
usemtl Material
s off
f 6/1/1 1/2/1 5/3/1
f 7/4/2 2/5/2 6/6/2
f 8/7/3 3/8/3 7/9/3
f 5/10/4 4/11/4 8/12/4
f 2/13/5 4/11/5 1/14/5
f 7/4/6 5/15/6 8/12/6
f 6/1/1 2/16/1 1/2/1
f 7/4/2 3/17/2 2/5/2
f 8/7/3 4/18/3 3/8/3
f 5/10/4 1/19/4 4/11/4
f 2/13/5 3/17/5 4/11/5
f 7/4/6 6/20/6 5/15/6
```

Here is the way I'm loading the texture to OpenGL:

```
unsigned char* localBuffer = stbi_load(filepath.c_str(), &this->width, &this->height, &this->bitsPerPixel, 4);

glGenTextures(1, &this->id);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + this->slot);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->id);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, this->width, this->height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, localBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Here is the the vertex shader:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 vTextureCoords;

uniform mat4 Mvp;

void main()
{
   vTextureCoords = textureCoords;
   gl_Position = Mvp * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

Here is the fragment shader:

```
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 vTextureCoords;

uniform sampler2D textureSlot;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(textureSlot, vTextureCoords);
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems like the right side triangles of your cube are not rendering. How does the front and right side of your cube look from the inside?

Comment: @Sync it From inside the cube all the sides look normal. That "transparency effect" seems to appear from any position/angle I look at the cube (from outside)

Comment: Is depth testing enabled?I don't think your texture is the problem

Comment: @Sync it No, it was not enabled. That was the problem. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Post that as your answer so we can close this

Comment: can be done in fragment shader . like that  `if(gl_FrontFacing)
 gl_FragColor = texture( t, kn);
 else discard;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Sync it I find out that the solution was to enable depth testing.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: @Sync it Ok, I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer

Comment: sometimes `GL_CULL_FACE` enabled can do this too if your winding rule is set wrongly `glFrontFace(GL_CW/GL_CCW)` or the faces are inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a very similar issue, however I'm using DirectX. The reason was that I didn't have the depth-stencil buffer set and I so the pixel depth values were being overridden by whatever order they were drawn in first. Check to make sure you have some equivalent of this enabled in OpenGl.

Comment: Yep, it was the same problem as yours, I have posted the solution above